Is this atomic reference counting optimisation safe in C?
Is this code safe knowing that:

Header_mark_as_shared is always only called before an object crosses to other threads, no matter in which thread it resides in
The first call to Header_mark_as_shared will always happen in a single threaded context
Following calls to Header_mark_as_shared will always read is_shared as 1

I’m using the __atomic intrinsics from GCC and Clang.
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Header {
    uint8_t is_shared;
    uint64_t reference_count;
} Header;

void
Header_mark_as_shared(
    Header * const self
) {
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        ++self->reference_count;
        self->is_shared = 1;
    } else {
        __atomic_fetch_add(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    }
}

void
Header_acquire(
    Header * const self
) {
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        ++self->reference_count;
    } else {
        __atomic_fetch_add(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    }
}

uint8_t
Header_release(
    Header * const self
) {
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        return !--self->reference_count;
    } else {
        return __atomic_fetch_sub(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL) == 1;
    }
}

uint8_t
Header_is_one(
    Header const * const self
) {
    if (!self->is_shared) {
        return self->reference_count == 1;
    } else {
        return __atomic_load_n(&self->reference_count, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE) == 1;
    }
}


The __atomic_* functions are not standard so, while we can guess what they do, we can't be sure because you've not identified what they do or where they are defined.  Their names are reserved for the implementation, of course, so you have presumably not defined them yourself.

Those functions are the atomic intrinsics from GCC and Clang.

@JoãoPires, C has perfectly good standard atomic manipulation functions, and atomic types.  You should use them in favor of implementation-specific internal functions.  But if you insist upon using implementation-specific functions and asking questions about them here, then you should tag one(!) implementation and focus the question on that one.

Additionally, are you sure you're asking about C, and not C++?  The linked documentation refers to the C++ memory model and describes the functions as being overloaded, which is not compatible with C, though I guess it's possible that GCC uses internal compiler magic to make the overloading work, since these are internal intrinsics.

@JohnBollinger: Standard C stdatomic.h doesn't AFAIK support the functionality of C++20 atomic_ref to let you make some operations atomic, some non-atomic, on the same object.  I guess the solution here would be a union { _Atomic unsigned long rc_atomic; unsigned long rc; };  (not uint64_t; that would be unnecessarily slow on 32-bit platforms and waste space on 64-bit).

@JohnBollinger: I added the link to GCC's docs for its builtins.  They work identically in C and C++.  (And the C11 memory model is intentionally consistent with C++11's).  They're true builtins (not library functions) so they can be overloaded without any problem. (And actually, C11 has generic functions like atomic_load_explicit for all atomic types).  The libatomic library functions that are called if necessary have the size in the name, not the full type info, e.g __atomic_load_8.

This still has the bug pointed out in comments and answers to your previous question (Is this a correct implementation of atomic reference counting in C?) that is_shared is read non-atomically, which is a problem since you still have functions other than Craig's Header_new which modify it.  You have data-race UB which could easily in practice lead to code using this in a loop and only loading p->is_shared into a register once ahead of the loop and continuing to use the non-atomic path.

What exactly does "The first call to Header_mark_as_shared will always happen in a single threaded context" mean? I'm guessing from context that your intent is to say that the first call to that function for any given self occurs before that object is accessed by any thread other than the one in which that call occurs. But I would ordinarily interpret "single-threaded context" to mean that the process has only one thread, which is quite different.

Is "Following calls to Header_mark_as_shared will always read is_shared as 1" ensured by other code not shown, or is that an assertion about effects of the implementation of Header_mark_as_shared() presented in the question?

@JohnBollinger, all objects are initialised with is_shared as 0. Then, before the object gets sent to another thread, that value is changed to 1. That’s the only time is_shared is mutated and it remains with that value for the rest of its lifetime. is_shared only gets mutated once, on the same thread in which the object was originally created. Thus, further reads from is_shared will always yield the same immutable value of 1.

@JohnBollinger, was my explanation a bit more clear now?

The first call to Header_mark_as_shared will always happen in a single threaded context - I missed that for my previous comment.  As long as is_shared isn't changed after the struct is published to other threads, it's fine for them to be doing non-atomic reads of it since nobody's writing.

You write:


Header_mark_as_shared is always only called before an object crosses to other threads, no matter in which thread it resides in


Except possibly for objects with thread storage duration, it is fraught to think of objects as "resid[ing] in" threads. Especially objects that you suppose may eventually be accessed by more than one thread.  Thread ownership of shared objects may be an application-level concept in some programs, but it is not a part of C language semantics.
I take:


The first call to Header_mark_as_shared will always happen in a single threaded context


as an assertion that the first call to Header_mark_as_shared() for any given self argument will occur before *self is accessed by any thread other than the one in which that call occurs.  That's not necessarily a "single threaded context", which is a context in which the process has only one (live) thread.
Your commentary on the question seems to confirm my interpretation.
I take:


Following calls to Header_mark_as_shared will always read is_shared as 1


to be an assertion about the effects of calling Header_mark_as_shared() as described in the previous two points, as opposed to an assertion about the effects of other code not presented in the question.  You seem to have confirmed this in commentary on the question.

With those considerations,

Is this atomic reference counting optimisation safe in C?

NO.
Issue 1
self->is_shared is accessed non-atomically in all cases shown, so if *self is accessed by more than one thread then something else needs to provide appropriate memory ordering in order to avoid data races.  Atomic accesses with relaxed memory ordering do not order accesses to objects other than the one accessed atomically, so we don't even need to do any control flow analysis to see that

        __atomic_fetch_add(&self->reference_count, 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);


does not provide the needed ordering.  Neither does anything else shown.
Note well that this means that your assertion about threads other than the first to access a given object always seeing is_shared as 1 is not supported by the code presented.
Issue 2
Additionally, only some accesses to self->reference_count are atomic.  No two atomic accesses to the same object produce a data race, regardless of those accesses' memory ordering type, but the same is not true when at least one of the accesses is non-atomic.  Thus, even when these functions are used consistently with your description, you have data races involving self->reference_count as soon as a second thread calls any of the functions presented.
Issue 3
It's unclear exactly what you expect the self->reference_count accesses with acquire and acquire / release memory ordering to achieve for you, but it's unlikely that they are achieving it.
In particular, even if we ignore the data races already described, only Header_release() performs a release on self->reference_count, so it orders non-atomic accesses only between different calls to itself.  Calls to Header_mark_as_shared() and Header_acquire() do not order non-atomic accesses at all.  Calls to Header_is_one() order non-atomic accesses relative only to preceding calls to Header_release().
Possible issue 4
None of the functions presented perform locking or any analog of it, so they do nothing to protect against data races involving members of *self other than reference_count.  It could be, however, that a combination of these functions with others not shown would have that effect.

Recommendation
You seem to be trying to provide for thread-safe reference counting (at least) without incurring a performance penalty in the event that an object is only ever accessed by a single thread.  I don't think this is possible, at least not without relying on considerably more implementation and architecture details than you currently are doing.  If you want to protect only the reference count then dump is_shared and just perform all accesses to reference_count atomically, with relaxed memory ordering.  Revisit this only if your performance measurements identify it as a significant bottleneck.
However, I suspect that you are indeed going to want a mechanism to avoid data races for more than just the reference count.  In that case, all this business with atomic reference counting is probably pointless.  Whatever mechanism you use to protect the rest of your objects' members (mutex, atomic spinlock, etc.), if used correctly for that purpose, should be effective for protecting the reference counts too.  In that case, you would get your wanted optimization for no additional cost by dumping is_shared and implementing a naive, non-atomic reference count.

I still don’t get why is_shared is unsafe. Like I’ve said before, is_shared only gets mutated once, before the object gets sent to other threads. After that is_shared remains unchanged.

The moment is_shared gets accessed by multiple threads its value will already always be 1, because it has already been changed before in a context where it was safe to do so. As far as the memory ordering that the acquire and release functions use, those are the same as the ones recommended by Boost and as used by Google on their ARC implementation.

Boost recommendation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_reference_counters, Google ARC implementation: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/atomic_ref_count.h

@JoãoPires, your remark "The moment is_shared gets accessed by multiple threads its value will already always be 1" assumes a sequentially consistent view of memory, which your code explicitly avoids providing for.  This is a large part of what data races are about.  The first access to an object by a given thread has no inherent memory ordering semantics associated with it.  If you don't provide for appropriate memory ordering then the second thread to access one of your objects might not see is_shared's value as 1.

@JoãoPires, your Boost example does not involve an analog of your is_shared.  It implements the case described in this answer that you want thread safety only for the reference count itself.  Same for the Google ARC example.

@JoãoPires, I don't think those examples' accesses with acquire and acquire / release semantics serve any useful purpose for the reference counting itself, but I anticipate that they serve an external purpose.  They have no relevance to ordering the atomic accesses.

Are you saying that: main thread creates object; main thread increments and decrements the reference count of said object; main thread then sets object as shared and sends it it to a pthread; on the context of the new thread, there’s now no guarantees that is_shared is indeed 1? That doesn’t make much sense to me …

@JoãoPires, it depends on exactly what you mean by "sends it to a new thread".  If the thread that writes is_shared starts a new thread after that write, and makes the object accessible to that thread, then the new thread creation serves to order writes by the initial thread occurring (in that thread) before the thread creation prior to accesses by the new thread.  But that's a rather special case.  The same does not automatically follow if a different thread starts the new thread, or if the initial thread initializes the object after the other thread is already running. [...]

[...] Perhaps those cases are not relevant to your particular application, but in general, they cannot be ignored.  In such cases, yes, without any other support, the second and subsequent threads to access the object might read is_shared as other than 1.  The C and C++ memory models intentionally permit this, mostly for performance reasons.  At the level of generality of the question posed, then, again, your optimization is not thread safe.

The order of events, no matter the thread the object is in, is always the same: Header_mark_as_shared is called; new thread gets created; object gets passed to the new thread (in case of a pthread, it gets passed as a void pointer argument to pthread_create); object now gets dereferenced and copied to some thread local specific data structure without having its reference count incremented.

That specific order of events can happen in a nested manner, in each threads spawn further threads.

in which threads may spawn further threads*

Again, @JoãoPires, creation of a new thread is a synchronization event.  All actions of a thread are ordered after creation of that thread.  How and whether the thread creation is ordered with respect to other actions depends on various factors.  The specific behavior pattern you describe will not expose you to data races involving is_shared, but the question does not convey that particular pattern, and there are many others for which your code is not safe.

Moreover, @JoãoPires, I would be inclined to guess that if you have such tight control over how your objects are accessed and shared, then you can probably do without reference counting at all. That would be an even better optimization, for little or no additional effort than the reference counting is costing you.

This is for a stack based VM that I’m making, so yes, I do have 100% control over how objects are accessed and shared. That said, then, my solution for that particular use case is 100% safe? Correct?

@JoãoPires, when the functions presented in the question are used according to the pattern you have described in these comments, that usage itself does not produce any data races involving the is_shared or reference_count members of the accessed objects.  Issues 3 and 4 described in this answer remain, independent of usage pattern.  If there are any accesses to the reference_count members other than via the functions presented, now or in the future, then they may impact thread safety.  And of course, all bets are off if you do not adhere strictly to the pattern you describe.

I concur that access to is_shared is safe in the intended use-case, which is under-documented.  Header_mark_as_shared must only be called before release/acquire synchronization publishes this struct to other threads.  (Or before creation of new threads that access it.) Like John, I'm also unclear as to the purpose of acq_rel decrements but relaxed increments.  Something about callers of these functions calling free?  (@JoãoPires).  The other acquire is in is_one, which is again undocumented as to use-case.

This is mainly used to implement copy on write operations. The release function returning true when there's no more references is to signal to the caller that it is safe to call  free. The is_one function tells the caller whether it is safe or not to mutate the object. This answers all my doubts and questions that I had. Thank you all for all your help and support. Next time I'll try to explain myself better. Happy New Years Eve for everyone too!
